# After raise event control not given to caller immediately

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net mvc 4.7.2 site.  I have class that raises event and I handle the event in another class.  So my code looks something like:

```
        RedirectDeleting?.Invoke(this,new RedirectDeletingArgs(contentId,culture));

        _redirectUrlService.Delete(id);

        RedirectDeleted?.Invoke(this,new RedirectDeletedArgs(contentId,culture));
```

In the handler my code looks like:

```
RedirectsService.RedirectDeleted += RedirectsService_RedirectDeleted;

        private void RedirectsService_RedirectDeleted(object sender, RedirectDeletedArgs e)
    {
        RemoveRedirectFromStorage(e);
    }
```

I am expecting the event RedirectDeleting to be raised first, then control going to the handler so in my other class the method RedirectsService_RedirectDeleted should be called.

What is happening is the event is raised execution in class raising event continues then my event gets handled by which time its too late.  My handler needs to execute before the method _redirectUrlService.Delete is called.

I am not doing anything async etc.  Am i missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: What are you doing in the handler of RedirectDeleting? Please post it

Comment: ok, with a bit more digging looks like the method its calling via a dispatcher somewhere along the way something is async and that is causing the ordering issue.